# Shared terms in an arithmetic sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

I have a two arithmetic progressions (or arithmetic sequences):

- 2, 10, 18, ...
- 5, 8, 11, ...

They say to you that this two arithmetic sequences have 41 shared terms (terms I mean by $a_1$, $a_{45}$, for example).
They ask:

```
At least how many terms are there in each sequence?
```

I don't know how to even begin. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Hint: Check $26$ and $50$ are in both sequences. Consider what this suggests.

Comment: @Henry Is there some fast ways to get through this? I mean, let's say they put it in just a part of an exam, or does it take time...?

Comment: @Henry I don't know what it suggests actually. And I haven't done in school so much, we saw just $a_n = a_1 + (n-1)d$

Comment: Consider $2,10,18,\mathbf{26},34,42,\mathbf{50},\ldots$ and $5,8,11,14,17,20,23,\mathbf{26},29,32,35,38,41,44,47,\mathbf{50},\ldots$, the gaps between these and how many you need to get $41$ shared terms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested in comments:

Hint: Consider $$2,10,18,\mathbf{26},34,42,\mathbf{50},\ldots$$ and $$5,8,11,14,17,20,23,\mathbf{26},29,32,35,38,41,44,47,\mathbf{50},\ldots$$

the gaps between these and how many you need to get $41$ shared terms